# Python: clear existing string in search box using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am using webdriver to login into a website at the moment. There is a table search which already have a digit "50" in it. I want to change it to "300".

Code snippet:

```
no="300"
blank = driver.find_element_by_id("PC1_PageSize")
blank.send_keys(no)
```

But when I tried this, it became "50300". My expected result is to replace "50" to "300". Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to *write* new value into input field instead of *appending* it, you should call `clear()` before `send_keys()`:

```
no="300"
blank = driver.find_element_by_id("PC1_PageSize")
blank.clear()
blank.send_keys(no)
```